# バッチファイル処理結果のテキスト保存について

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

iperfというツールを定期的にバッチで起動し、結果を日時と実行結果をテキストに保存したいのですが、
日時処理を入れると、動作しません。何が悪いのかさっぱり分からない状態です。

```
echo %date%
echo %time%
set yyyy=%date:~0,4%
set mm=%date:~5,2%
set dd=%date:~8,2%
set time2=%time: =0% 
set hh=%time2:~0,2%
set mn=%time2:~3,2%
 
set filename=%yyyy%-%mm%%dd%-%hh%%mn%

filename >> test.log
iperf3.exe -c 192.168.3.6 >> test.log
```

iperf実行結果

```
ここに日時を入れたいです。

Connecting to host 192.168.3.6, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.3.2 port 61320 connected to 192.168.3.6 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  10.1 MBytes  84.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   1.00-2.01   sec  9.12 MBytes  76.2 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   2.01-3.01   sec  9.88 MBytes  82.6 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   3.01-4.01   sec  9.00 MBytes  75.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   4.01-5.00   sec  9.62 MBytes  81.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  8.00 MBytes  67.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  8.00 MBytes  67.0 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  8.75 MBytes  73.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   8.00-9.01   sec  9.50 MBytes  79.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   9.01-10.01  sec  10.4 MBytes  87.4 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.01  sec  92.4 MBytes  77.4 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.01  sec  92.4 MBytes  77.4 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問に貼られたバッチを1行ずつ実行していくと、以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
'filename' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

---

日付を出力する部分では、実際には以下のように `%変数名%` の形で変数を展開する必要があると思います。

```
echo %filename% >> test.log
```

Comment: ```echo %date%%time% >> test.log``` とすることでも無理やりですが、実現できました。